# How do I delete a package that I accidentally published to go.dev?

Tags: go, go-packages

I accidentally published a package to go.dev website, can anyone tell me how to delete it?

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Nksama/Random-quotes

Comment: On top of the retract answers, go proxies will cache a package, even after the repo has been deleted. So as you've probably learned already, be very careful what you publish to the internet.

Answer (score 8):

Published modules cannot be deleted but can be retracted.  A retracted version still exists and can be downloaded (so builds that depend on it won't break), but the go command won’t select it automatically when resolving. More info [here](https://blog.golang.org/go116-module-changes#TOC_5.).

To retract you will have to add retract directive to your go.mod. For example

```
retract v1.0.0
retract [v1.0.0, v1.9.9]
retract (
    v1.0.0
    [v1.0.0, v1.9.9]
)
```

Please Note :

> The retract directive was added in Go 1.16. Go 1.15 and lower will
> report an error if a retract directive is written in the main module's
> go.mod file and will ignore retract directives in go.mod files of
> dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

There's package removal guide on the site: https://go.dev/about/

Basically you need to put `retract` directive in your `go.mod` file and publish new version.